# Proper way to add noise to signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, noise

In many areas I have found that while adding noise, we mention some specification like zero mean and variance. I need to add AWGN, colored noise, uniform noise of varying SNR in Db. The following code shows the way how I generated and added noise. I am aware of the function `awgn()` but it is a kind of black box thing without knowing how the noise is getting added. So, can somebody please explain the correct way to generate and add noise. Thank you

```
SNR = [-10:5:30]; %in Db
snr = 10 .^ (0.1 .* SNR);

for I = 1:length(snr)
    noise = 1 / sqrt(2) * (randn(1, N) + 1i * randn(1, N));
    u = y + noise .* snr(I);
end
```

Comment: You can view all of the code for `awgn` and `wgn` that is used under the hood: type `edit awgn` or `edit wgn` in your command window.

Comment: Steven, Is the signal power calculation correct? If you check the definitions:
http://www.gaussianwaves.com/2013/12/power-and-energy-of-a-signal/
You will not find an sqrt there ...
Moreover without sqrt the signal power calculated by your formulae and by using variances are the same (they should be).

Comment: I am kind of confused due to the many different versions of adding noise to signal. I don't want to use the `awgn()` function and based only on the theory wanted to know how to add complex noise of a specific variance and a specific signal to noise ratio value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm adding another answer since it strikes me that Steven's is not quite correct and Horchler's suggestion to look inside function `awgn` is a good one.

Either MATLAB or Octave (in the communications toolbox) have a function `awgn` that adds (white Gaussian) noise to attain a desired signal-to-noise power level; the following is the relevant portion of the code (from the Octave function):

```
  if (meas == 1)  % <-- if using signal power to determine appropriate noise power
    p = sum( abs( x(:)) .^ 2) / length(x(:));
    if (strcmp(type,"dB"))
      p = 10 * log10(p);
    endif
  endif

  if (strcmp(type,"linear"))
    np = p / snr;
  else   % <-- in dB
    np = p - snr;
  endif

  y = x + wgn (m, n, np, 1, seed, type, out);
```

As you can see by the way `p` (the power of the input data) is computed, the answer from Steven does not appear to be quite right.

You can ask the function to compute the total power of your data array and combine that with the desired s/n value you provide to compute the appropriate power level of the added noise. You do this by passing the string "measured" among the optional inputs, like this (see [here](http://octave.sourceforge.net/communications/function/awgn.html) for the Octave documentation or [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/awgn.html) for the MATLAB documentation):

```
     y = awgn (x, snr, 'measured')
```

This leads ultimately to `meas=1` and so `meas==1` being true in the code above. The function `awgn` then uses the signal passed to it to compute the signal power, and from this and the desired s/n it then computes the appropriate power level for the added noise.

As the documentation further explains

> By default the snr and pwr are assumed to be in dB and dBW
>   respectively. This default behavior can be chosen with type set to
>   "dB". In the case where type is set to "linear", pwr is assumed to be
>   in Watts and snr is a ratio.

This means you can pass a negative or 0 dB snr value. The result will also depend then on other options you pass, such as the string "measured".

For the MATLAB case I suggest reading the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/awgn.html), it explains how to use the function `awgn` in different scenarios. Note that implementations in Octave and MATLAB are not identical, the computation of noise power should be the same but there may be different options.

And here is the relevant part from `wgn` (called above by `awgn`):

```
  if (strcmp(type,"dBW"))
    np = 10 ^ (p/10);
  elseif (strcmp(type,"dBm"))
    np = 10 ^((p - 30)/10);
  elseif (strcmp(type,"linear"))
    np = p;
  endif

  if(!isempty(seed))
    randn("state",seed);
  endif

  if (strcmp(out,"complex"))
    y = (sqrt(imp*np/2))*(randn(m,n)+1i*randn(m,n)); % imp=1 assuming impedance is 1 Ohm
  else
    y = (sqrt(imp*np))*randn(m,n);
  endif
```

If you want to check the power of your noise (`np`), the `awgn` and `awg` functions assume the following relationships hold:

```
  np = var(y,1);        % linear scale
  np = 10*log10(np);    % in dB
```

where `var(...,1)` is the *population* variance for the noise `y`.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this problem again. I don't quite follow how to apply the variables meas (where is it used). Also, how does this treat the negative and zero SNR? Say, if SNR = -10 as a number or SNR = 0 ?

Comment: @SKM please see added explanations

Comment: @SKM also added a correction regarding relation of power and real/complex data.

Answer (score 4):

Most answers here forget that SNR is specified in decibels. Therefore, you shouldn't encounter 'division by 0' error, because you should really divide by `10^(targetSNR/10)` which is never negative nor zero for real `targetSNR`.

Answer (score 3):

This 'should not divide by 0' problem could be easily solved if you add a condition to check if targetSNR is 0 and do these only if it is not 0. When your target SNR is 0, it means it's pure noise.

```
function out_signal = addAWGN(signal, targetSNR)
sigLength = length(signal); % length
awgnNoise = randn(size(signal)); % orignal noise
pwrSig = sqrt(sum(signal.^2))/sigLength; % signal power
pwrNoise = sqrt(sum(awgnNoise.^2))/sigLength; % noise power
if targetSNR ~= 0
   scaleFactor = (pwrSig/pwrNoise)/targetSNR; %find scale factor
   awgnNoise = scaleFactor*awgnNoise; 
   out_signal = signal + awgnNoise; % add noise
else
   out_signal = awgnNoise; % noise only
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use randn() to generate a noise vector 'awgnNoise' of the length you want. Then, given a specified SNR value, calculate the power of the orignal signal and the power of the noise vector 'awgnNoise'. 
Get the right amplitude scaling factor for the noise vector and just scale it.

The following code is an example to corrupt signal with white noise, assuming input signal is 1D and real valued.

```
function out_signal = addAWGN(signal, targetSNR)
sigLength = length(signal); % length
awgnNoise = randn(size(signal)); % orignal noise
pwrSig = sqrt(sum(signal.^2))/sigLength; % signal power
pwrNoise = sqrt(sum(awgnNoise.^2))/sigLength; % noise power

scaleFactor = (pwrSig/pwrNoise)/targetSNR; %find scale factor
awgnNoise = scaleFactor*awgnNoise; 
out_signal = signal + awgnNoise; % add noise
```

Be careful about the sqrt(2) factor when you deal with complex signal, if you want to generate the real and imag part separately.

Comment: Forgot to ask a question, if you may kindly reply to it - For complex signal, you mentioned about sqrt(2). Is it how I should go about the way I have posted in my question? Or something else? Could you please show for complex signal as well? Secondly, how do I know when a signal is complex?

Comment: Whether it is complex depends the physical meaning of the signal in your simulation, e.g. it would be complex if it is quadrature modulated signal. If you mean in matlab, you can use isreal() function.

Comment: Apologies to bother you again after so long.I ran your code earlier & did not face a problem when the targetSNR is not zero dB.In the variable scaleFactor,you are dividng the ratio(powersignal and pwrNoise)by the targetSNR.If targetSNR=0, then scaleFactor will go to infty.Generally,the signal power is fixed,&we want to generate an output which has the targetSNR. Why do we divide by targetSNR?Could you please explain