# Matlab: Generate noisy signal for particular SNR and particular variance

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, noise

In general when we add noise to a signal `x=rand(1,100)`, this is one way

```
 sigma_2_v = 0.5;
noisy_signal = rand(1,100) + sqrt(sigma_2_v)*randn(1,100);
```

There is another method found here:
[Proper way to add noise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690766/proper-way-to-add-noise-to-signal)

For my case, I need to have the information about the variance of the noise, `sigma_2_v`, and generate noisy signal by varying `sigma_2_v`. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you explain what you mean by "_I need to have the information about the variance of the noise_" ? And what king of noise do you need : Gaussian noise ?

Comment: Ok, so what's wrong with the method of your original post ? It should work straight away if you place it in a loop in which you vary sigma.

Comment: Well, in your case the `SNR` is just the ratio between the average value of the signal `µ` and the standard deviation of this signal `σ`. So knowing the SNR you just have to evaluate `µ` and `σ` will be `µ/SNR`. Why do you say "_It is mentioned_" ? Is this your homework ?

Comment: Yes, in the case of a Gaussian noise with a signal that has a well-defined mean value this is as simple as that.

Comment: @SrishtiM I added a new answer to the question you linked to which i think addresses your problem. In general the variance of the noise is the same as the power level.

Comment: I added an answer, hope it makes things clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of possible conventions used to define a s/n ratio, a common one being based on the notion of signal and noise power. If the total power of the spectrum is `p` and the noise power is `np`, then the signal-to-noise can be written as `snr = p - np`, when the power is in dB units, or `snr = p/np`, when the power is in linear units.

The MATLAB (and Octave equivalent) function `awgn` adds (white Gaussian) noise to an input data array to the desired final s/n power level, specified by default in dB. The function `awgn` uses another function `wgn` to generate an array representing the noise at a desired noise power level. The noise is sampled from a Gaussian distribution (it is *not* rescaled to make the variance of the points in the array equal exactly the desired noise power level, [as some suggest you do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690766/proper-way-to-add-noise-to-signal/23690881#23690881); do not rescale the noise: if you rescale the points sampled from the noise distribution, then the points will (obviously) not necessarily reflect the desired noise distribution or the desired power level!). You can specify the amount of noise to add to your data via `awgn` in a number of non-default ways, for instance: a) by specifying the power of the input data (the default is 0 dB), or b) by asking the routine to compute the power of the input data using the formula `p = var(data,1)`, where var(...,1) implies computation of the population variance. In either case the routine computes the required noise power level using the formula `np = p-snr` (in dB).

The excellent MATLAB documentation provides a good description of the [awgn](http://se.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/awgn.html) routine.